# How to update content using JavaScript without showing that it is refreshing "blink"?

Tags: javascript

I m trying to update content in my page without refreshing the whole page just by refreshing the div using javascript.

However it does the job, the output is giving the "blink" at set interval to update content.

How can i avoid to hide the "blink" while updating the content.

Here's the code so far :

**index.php**

```
<!doctype html public "-//w3c//dtd html 3.2//en">
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body >


<div id="curve_chart"></div>
<br><br>


<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready( function(){
$('#curve_chart').load('load.php');
refresh();
});

function refresh()
{
    setTimeout( function() {
      $('#curve_chart').load('load.php');
      refresh();
    }, 2000);
}
</script>
</body></html>
```

the load.php contains the content which comes from db.

Now , how do i update the content fetched in load.php in index.php without giving the blink effect for every 2 sec of set interval.

Thanks in advance for every single soul who took a min in going through this. I respect your time.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use  `.ajax` for the call and see if the blinking goes away. `.load` sometimes recreates the element rather than update it and that causes the blinking when fetching a large amount of data

Edit:

```
$.ajax({url: "demo_test.php", success: function(result){
    $("#curve_chart").html(result);
}});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the time. can you provide me any ajax code related to thre above scenario.

Comment: is this how it should go.. 

`<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready( function(){
$('#curve_chart').load('load.php');
refresh();
});
 
$.ajax({url: "load.php", success: function(result){
    $("#curve_chart").html(result);
}});
</script>`

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Thank you all for your time and taking a look at it.

All i had to do is to shift the data fetching code as well as just the data interpreting code to the load.php which is getting refreshed every set interval time. leave the rest divs or sections behind in index page.

Thanks once again.